# Java Multithreading Using locks to achieve method level locking

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, locking

```
public class MainLock {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        LockClass lock = new LockClass();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lock.incrementa();
            }
        });
        
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lock.incrementb();
            }
        });
        
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lock.incrementa();
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

```
public class LockClass {
    int a;
    int b;
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    public void incrementa() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                System.out.println("a " + a++);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            lock.unlock();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void incrementb() {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                System.out.println("b " + b++);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            lock.unlock();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output above result is
a0 a1 a2 b0 b1 b2 a3 a4 a5

I want to achieve  a0 b0 a1 b1 a2 b2 a3 a4 a5, thread t1 and t2 should run parallely and t3 should be blocked because of lock by t1.

1. I know using static synchronization in incrementb() will work but I am looking something only with locks.
2. I am looking for Method level locking, not object level or class level

I there any way in java to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking something only with locks

That's not what locks are for. Pretty much the *only* thing you should use locks* for is to ensure safe access to shared variables. You should not try to use locks for signaling between threads.

> I want to achieve a0 b0 a1 b1 a2 b2...

The best way to make certain things happen in a certain order is to do all of those things in the same thread. You *can* make threads take turns like that, but it completely defeats the purpose of using threads. The purpose of using threads is to allow different parts of a program to run [*concurrently*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)), and that is exactly what you are *not* allowing the threads to do when you force them to take turns.

---

If you really *want* to make the threads take turns (e.g., if this is a homework assignment**) then IMO the best way to do that is to pass a virtual *token* from thread to thread. Holding the token means, "it's your turn."

One way to do it is to use [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) objects: Make one semaphore per thread, but give each thread a reference to *two* of them. Each thread will use one semaphore to receive the token, and the other semaphore to pass the token off to the next thread:

```java
class MyRunnable {
    private Semaphore token_in;
    private Semaphore token_out;

    public MyRunnable(Semaphore token_in, Semaphore token_out) {
        this.token_in = token_in;
        this.token_out = token_out;
    }

    public void Run() {
        while (...thread should keep running...) {
            token_in.acquire();  // wait to receive the token.
            ...do stuff...
            token_out.release(); // hand the token to the next thread.
        }
    }
}
```

When you start this up, you must make sure that each thread's `token_out` is the next thread's `token_in`:

```java
static void main(...) {
    int TOKEN = 1;
    int EMPTY = 0;
    Semaphore s1 = new Semaphore(TOKEN);
    Semaphore s2 = new Semaphore(EMPTY);
    Semaphore s3 = new Semaphore(EMPTY);

    MyRunnable r1 = new MyRunnable(s1, s2);
    MyRunnable r2 = new MyRunnable(s2, s3);
    MyRunnable r3 = new MyRunnable(s3, s1);

    ...create and start the three threads for r1, r2, and r3...
}
```

---

* "Locks" includes any use of a `synchronized` block or a `synchronized` method or a `ReentrantLock`.

** If you want to tell your instructor what I said about making threads take turns, that's up to you. You'd be doing the world a favor if you can help eradicate this assignment, but only you can decide whether it's politically smart to talk to your instructor about ideas that are above the level of what they're teaching.