# Python Lock always re-acquired by the same thread

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I got this as an interview problem a few days ago. I don't really know parallel programming, and the obvious solution I've tried isn't working.

The question is: write two functions, one printing "foo", one printing "bar", that will be run on separate threads. How to ensure output is always:

```
foo
bar
foo
bar
...
```

Here's what I've tried:

```py
from threading import Lock, Thread


class ThreadPrinting:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = Lock()
        self.count = 10

    def foo(self):
        for _ in range(self.count):
            with self.lock:
                print("foo")

    def bar(self):
        for _ in range(self.count):
            with self.lock:
                print("bar")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tp = ThreadPrinting()
    t1 = Thread(target=tp.foo)
    t2 = Thread(target=tp.bar)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

But this just produces 10 "foo"s and then 10 "bar"s. Seemingly the same thread manages to loop around and re-acquire the lock before the other. What might be the solution here? Thank you.

Comment: If I was asked this question in an interview, I would start by explaining why it is a _Bad Idea_ to make two threads do that, and only then would I tell them _how_ I could make two threads do it. My favorite technique, which can be generalized to any number of threads: Use semaphores or blocking queues to pass a virtual (if semaphores) or actual (if blocking queues) token back and forth between the threads. The token is like a "[talking stick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talking_stick)." A thread must wait until it is given the stick before it is allowed to "speak."

Comment: P.S.: It is a bad idea because the entire point of using threads is to allow the threads to run [_concurrently_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing) with one another. Any time you want certain things to happen in a certain order, the _best_ way to make that happen is to do all of those things in the same, single thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Solomon Slow provided a great explanation and pointed me in the right direction. I initially wanted some kind of a "lock with value" that can be acquired only conditionally. But this doesn't really exist, and busy-waiting in a cycle of "acquire lock - check variable - loop around" is not great. Instead I solved this with a pair of threading.Condition objects that the threads use to talk to each other. I'm sure there's a simpler solution, but here's mine:

```py
from threading import Thread, Condition


class ThreadPrinting:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fooCondition = Condition()
        self.barCondition = Condition()
        self.count = 10

    def foo(self):
        for _ in range(self.count):
            with self.fooCondition:
                self.fooCondition.wait()
                print("foo")
                with self.barCondition:
                    self.barCondition.notify()

    def bar(self):
        with self.fooCondition:
            self.fooCondition.notify()  # Bootstrap the cycle
        for _ in range(self.count):
            with self.barCondition:
                self.barCondition.wait()
                print("bar")
                with self.fooCondition:
                    self.fooCondition.notify()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tp = ThreadPrinting()
    t1 = Thread(target=tp.foo)
    t2 = Thread(target=tp.bar)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

> this just produces 10 "foo"s and then 10 "bar"s. Seemingly the same thread manages to loop around and re-acquire the lock before the other.

No surprise there. The problem with using a `threading.Lock` object (a.k.a., a "mutex") in this way is that, like the (default) mutexes in most programming systems, it makes no attempt to be [*fair*](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/70125/43896).

The very next thing that either of your two threads does after it releases the `lock` is, it immediately tries to acquire the lock again. Meanwhile, the other thread is sleeping (a.k.a., "blocked",) waiting for its turn to acquire the lock.

The goal of most operating systems, when there is heavy demand for CPU time, is to maximize the amount of useful work that the CPU(s) can do. The best way to do that is to award the lock to the thread that already is running on some CPU instead of wasting time waking up some other thread that is sleeping.

That strategy works well in programs that use locks the way locks were *meant* to be used—that is to say, programs where the threads spend most of their time unlocked, and only *briefly* grab a lock, every so often, in order to examine or update some (group of) shared variables.

---

In order to make your threads take turns printing their messages, you are going to need to find some way to let the threads explicitly say to each other, "It's your turn now."

See my comments on your question for a hint about how you might do that.

Comment: Could you clarify how your comment (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73336295/python-lock-always-re-acquired-by-the-same-thread#comment129517833_73336295) actually solves that issue though? It would seem that the thread incrementing a semaphore counter at the end of an iteration then immediately decrements it at start of the next, or putting a token into a queue at the end of an iteration then immediately gets it back at the start of the next; in both cases because that thread is the one that's 'already is running on some CPU' whilst the other one waiting 'is sleeping'

Comment: @oc, The trick is to have one semaphore for each thread. Each thread waits, trying to take the token from its own semaphore, then it does its thing, and then it passes the token to the semaphore for the _next_ thread.

Comment: So the idea would be to for thread 1 to decrement its own semaphore counter at the start of each iteration `semaphore1.acquire()` and increment the semaphore counter of thread 2 at the end of each iteration `semaphore2.release()`, and vice versa for thread 2 with `semaphore1`?

Comment: and with queues something similar I suppose, each thread gets from its own queue at the start of each iteration but puts into the other thread's queue at the end of each iteration?

Comment: @oc, That's exactly right. Here's how I did it in Java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70369095/801894 Should be easy to do the same in Python.

Answer (score 0):

@T. Spikes A little bit refactoring of your solution.

```
from threading import Thread, Condition


class ThreadPrinting:
    def __init__(self):
        self.condition = Condition()
        self.count = 10

    def foo(self):
        for i in range(self.count):
            with self.condition:
                self.condition.wait()
                print(f"foo")

    def bar(self):
        for i in range(self.count):
            with self.condition:
                self.condition.notify()
                print(f"bar")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tp = ThreadPrinting()
    t1 = Thread(target=tp.foo)
    t2 = Thread(target=tp.bar)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Answer (score -1):

The way I did it was just to have the first thread send 'foo' then 1 second of sleep before the second sends 'bar'. Both functions sleep for 2 seconds between sends. This allows for them to always alternate, sending one word per second.

```py
from threading import Thread
import time

def foo():
    num = 0
    while num < 10:
        print("foo")
        num = num + 1
        time.sleep(2)

def bar():
    num = 0
    while num < 10:
        print("bar")
        num = num + 1
        time.sleep(2)

t1 = Thread(target=foo)
t2 = Thread(target=bar)
t1.start()
time.sleep(1)
t2.start()
```

I tried this for 100 of each 'foo' and 'bar' and it still alternated.

Comment: `sleep()` cannot guarantee that the threads always go in the right order. The reason is, `sleep(n)` is allowed to take _any_ amount of time that is not less than `n` seconds. Usually it will be pretty close, but there will always be _some_ error, and every once in a while there could be a lot of error. If you let the program run for long enough, then eventually the error will accumulate until one of the threads goes out-of-turn.